How to Use OneSignal with Firestore for Personalized Push Notifications?
I'm working on a project where I need to send personalized push notifications to users based on data stored in Firestore. I am using OneSignal as the push notification service. I have already set up Firestore and OneSignal in my project, but I'm not sure how to integrate them to send personalized notifications.
Here are the specific steps I need help with:
Reading Data from Firestore: How can I efficiently read user-specific data from Firestore?
Sending Personalized Notifications: How can I use this data to send personalized push notifications using OneSignal?
My Setup:
Backend: Firebase Firestore
Push Notification Service: OneSignal
My Goals:
Retrieve user preferences and data from Firestore.
Use this data to send targeted push notifications via OneSignal.
What I Have Tried:
Firestore Setup: I have Firestore set up with collections that store user data.
OneSignal Setup: I have integrated OneSignal SDK into my project and can send general notifications.
